# XSLT copy/copy-of without keeping namespaces

Tags: xslt

Hi I have issue in the default namespace declaration. output xml elements are appended with the default namespace.

The input XML look like

```html
  <m:Request xmlns:m="http://www.NeededNamespace/1.4.0">
         <Details>
            <Records>50</Records>
            <Start>1</Start>
            <sortName>sortName</sortName>
         </Details>
         <search>
            <criteria>
               <comparative>
                  <Comparative>exactMatch</Comparative>
               </comparative>
               <name>STATECODE</name>
               <value>CO</value>
            </criteria>
            <criteria>
               <comparative>
                  <Comparative>exactMatch</Comparative>
               </comparative>
               <name>Version</name>
               <value>4.0</value>
            </criteria>
            <criteria>
               <comparative>
                  <Comparative>contains</Comparative>
               </comparative>
               <name>LEGALNAME</name>
               <value>Citizens State Bank</value>
            </criteria>
         </search>
      </m:Request>
```

The XSLT look like

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="t" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.NotRequirednamespace.com">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <!--Stylesheet to remove all namespaces from a document-->
   <!--NOTE: this will lead to attribute name clash, if an element contains
        two attributes with same local name but different namespace prefix-->
   <!--Nodes that cannot have a namespace are copied as such-->
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <soap:Header>
            <xys:To xmlns:xys="http://services.xys.com/framework/xysHeader/v2">
               <xys:version>9.0</xys:version>
               <xys:serviceName>DetailsManagement</xys:serviceName>
               <xys:QOS>DEFAULT</xys:QOS>
               <xys:operation>GetDetails</xys:operation>
            </xys:To>
            <ConsumerInfo xmlns="http://services.xys.com/framework/xysHeader/v2">
               <xysApplicationName>SAP</xysApplicationName>
               <xysCheckPermission>-1</xysCheckPermission>
               <xysConsumerPlatform>CS</xysConsumerPlatform>
               <xysLanguage>en</xysLanguage>
               <xysLocale>US</xysLocale>
               <xysLogLevel>false</xysLogLevel>
            </ConsumerInfo>
            <HeaderMetadata xmlns="http://services.xys.com/framework/xysHeader/v2">
               <metadataContractVersion>2.0</metadataContractVersion>
               <Id>414</Id>
               <Timestamp>2014-11-20T14:17:30.908-0500</Timestamp>
            </HeaderMetadata>
            <xys:favouriteSausage xmlns:xys="http://services.xys.com/framework/xysHeader/v2">cumberland</xys:favouriteSausage>
         </soap:Header>
         <soap:Body>
            <GetDetails xmlns="http://www.NeededNamespace/1.4.0">
               <Message id="" version="" bodyType="FS-XML" timeStampCreated="2015-10-11T10:15:25.9144403-04:00" sourceLogicalId="" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/industries/xys">
                  <ACGroup bodyCategory="" TPMode="RespondError"/>
                  <COMMAND>

                     <xsl:apply-templates/>

                  </COMMAND>
               </Message>
            </GetDetails>
         </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--template to copy elements-->
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.NeededNamespace/1.4.0">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--template to copy attributes-->
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--template to copy the rest of the nodes-->
   <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output XML what i am getting is

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Header>
<xys:To xmlns:xys="http://services.xys.com/framework/xysHeader/v2">
<xys:version>9.0</xys:version>
<xys:serviceName>DetailsManagement</xys:serviceName>
<xys:QOS>DEFAULT</xys:QOS>
<xys:operation>GetDetails</xys:operation>
</xys:To>
<ConsumerInfo xmlns="http://services.xys.com/framework/xysHeader/v2">
<xysApplicationName>SAP</xysApplicationName>
<xysCheckPermission>-1</xysCheckPermission>
<xysConsumerPlatform>CS</xysConsumerPlatform>
<xysLanguage>en</xysLanguage>
<xysLocale>US</xysLocale>
<xysLogLevel>false</xysLogLevel>
</ConsumerInfo>
<HeaderMetadata xmlns="http://services.xys.com/framework/xysHeader/v2">
<metadataContractVersion>2.0</metadataContractVersion>
<Id>414</Id>
<Timestamp>2014-11-20T14:17:30.908-0500</Timestamp>
</HeaderMetadata>
<xys:favouriteSausage xmlns:xys="http://services.xys.com/framework/xysHeader/v2">cumberland</xys:favouriteSausage>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<GetDetails xmlns="http://www.NeededNamespace/1.4.0">
<Message xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/industries/xys" id="" version="" bodyType="FS-XML" timeStampCreated="2015-10-11T10:15:25.9144403-04:00" sourceLogicalId="">
<ACGroup bodyCategory="" TPMode="RespondError"/>
<COMMAND>
<Request xmlns="http://www.NeededNamespace/1.4.0">
<Details>
<Records>50</Records>
<Start>1</Start>
<sortName>sortName</sortName>
</Details>
<search>
<criteria>
<comparative>
<Comparative>exactMatch</Comparative>
</comparative>
<name>STATECODE</name>
<value>CO</value>
</criteria>
<criteria>
<comparative>
<Comparative>exactMatch</Comparative>
</comparative>
<name>Version</name>
<value>4.0</value>
</criteria>
<criteria>
<comparative>
<Comparative>contains</Comparative>
</comparative>
<name>LEGALNAME</name>
<value>Citizens State Bank</value>
</criteria>
</search>
</Request>
</COMMAND>
</Message>
</GetDetails>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But in the result I am getting the element as

```
<Request xmlns="http://www.NeededNamespace/1.4.0">
```

But i want the result tag as like below

```
<Request>
```

I dont want to redeclare the namespace which is already declared in the root tag of the same. I have tried all the option i have known and tried for last few days. can you please help me on this.

Comment: Please post the **full**, exact output you would like to get.

Answer (score 3):

The input element has expanded name (local-part="Request", namespace="http://www.NeededNamespace/1.4.0"). If you don't want the output Request element to have a namespace declaration, then presumably you want it to be in the same namespace as its parent, that is you want its expanded name to be (local-part="Request", namespace="http://www.ibm.com/industries/xys"). An xsl:copy or xsl:copy-of instruction will never (even in 2.0) change the expanded name of the element being copied. So you can't achieve your desired output using xsl:copy or xsl:copy-of. You will need to create a new element with the same local name but a different namespace from the original, using `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.ibm.com/industries/xys"/>`.

Comment: Thanks Michael Kay. Your solution worked. :) Apologies for  late update.

Comment: The SO convention is not to thank the answerer in a comment, but to click on the tick-mark next to the answer to mark the answer as accepted. That's helpful to anyone who comes along later and finds the question as the result of a search.